# plt.show(block=True) launches a black plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a script using Matplotlib that will launch "countdown plots" in successive, one-second intervals. I had the plots working, but was running into problems trying to close them due to the blocking nature of plt.show(). I added the block=True parameter to plt.show() command, and everything closes and opens on time now, but all of my plots are just a black window. In line with other answers to similar questions, I've tried adding plt.ion(), but no luck. I'm using Python 2.7 and running this via command line (no IDE). Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time


# Running script in conjuction with command to move robot
# Will have to subscribe to something that tells me when the robot *actually* starts to move

robot_started = True


velocity = 0.2

distance = 1
time_to_goal = distance/velocity

init_time = str(time_to_goal)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


if robot_started:


    start_time = time.time()


    # Initial plot
    an = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    ax.plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an), linewidth=6)
    plt.annotate(xy=[-.25,0], s=init_time, size=30)
    ax.axis('equal')
    plt.show(block=False)

    time_left = int(time_to_goal)


    while time.time() < (start_time + time_to_goal):

        time.sleep(1)

        plt.close('all')

        time_left = time_left - 1

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        ax.plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an), linewidth=6)
        plt.annotate(xy=[-.25,0], s=time_left, size=30)
        ax.axis('equal')
        plt.show(block=False)

    # Reached goal - display goal image

    plt.cla()
    plt.close()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an), linewidth=6, color='green')
    plt.annotate(xy=[0,0], s="Goal", size=25)
    ax.axis('equal')
    plt.show(block=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `plt.ion()` you will enable the interactive mode. `plt.show()` will display the interactive window and plot any defined axis elements. `plt.gcf().canvas.draw()` will update the figure. You can remove any defined axis elements by invoking the `remove()` command, e.g. `ann.remove()`, this way you don't have to clear the plot and reinvoke it.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time


# Running script in conjuction with command to move robot
# Will have to subscribe to something that tells me when the robot *actually* starts to move

robot_started = True
velocity = 0.2
distance = 1
time_to_goal = distance/velocity
init_time = str(time_to_goal)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
if robot_started:
    start_time = time.time()
    # Initial plot
    an = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    ax.plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an), linewidth=6)
    ann=plt.annotate(xy=[-.25,0], s=init_time, size=30)
    ax.axis('equal')
    plt.ion() #set the interactive mode
    plt.show() # opens the interactive window and displays initial plot
    time_left = int(time_to_goal)
    k=1
    while time.time() < (start_time + time_to_goal):
        ann.remove()
        time.sleep(1)
        time_left = time_left - 1
        ax.plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an), linewidth=6)
        ann=plt.annotate(xy=[-.25,0], s=time_left, size=30)
        plt.gcf().canvas.draw() #updates the altered figure
        ax.axis('equal')
        plt.pause(1)
    #plt.cla()
    #plt.close()
    #fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ann.remove()
    ax.plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an), linewidth=6, color='green')
    plt.annotate(xy=[0,0], s="Goal", size=25)
    ax.axis('equal')
```

[image: circle]

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Comment: Happy to help. If you found the solution helpful, you want to check the green mark. This will help keep the focus on unanswered questions.